# React Native - RCTFatalException: Unhandled JS Exception: "version" is a required argument

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-ios

I'm doing a React Native App

(react-native: 0.43.4)

And I'm having problems on running Release schema on iOS.

I have Pods (Crashlytics) and I'm running my app through the Workspace Project.

On Debug schema it runs without a problem, when I switch to Release it throws this exception:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RCTFatalException: 
Unhandled JS Exception: "version" is a required argument.', 
reason: 'Unhandled JS Exception: "version" is a required argument., stack:
            a@551:111
            i@550:244
            o@550:143
            l@543:504
            <unknown>@381:901
            <unknown>@381:676
            <unknown>@381:851
            <unknown>@381:676
            go@381:525
            <unknown>@381:651
            <unknown>@381:651
            <unknown>@381:651
            <unknown>@381:651
            <unknown>@12:741
            i@2:965
            t@2:572
            global code@667:9
            '
            *** First throw call stack:
            (0x18f35efd8 0x18ddc0538 0x18f35ef20 0x1000e3010 0x1000dd54c 0x18f364e80 0x18f25a2b4 0x18f25ee7c 0x1000e0f6c 0x100106e0c 0x1001067bc 0x1005f1a50 0x1005f1a10 0x1005ff2e8 0x1005f5634 0x1005ff810 0x100601630 0x10060139c 0x18e41f1d0 0x18e41ed7c)
            libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I've been searching this exception although I haven't find a solution yet...

Any clue what this is?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error comes from your javascript

> Unhandled JS Exception

Since it's happening only on release mode, check any js code that is executed only in that mode (for example, search for any `if (!__DEV__)` or other flags you might use to distinguish between release and debug mode)